# Recommendation: Use the email and password of Woocommerce to log in though other application

Tags: php, laravel, api, woocommerce, webhooks

I have a Woocommerce store where the client can buy products.
I want to use the same login and password to log in to another application, which is built using the Laravel framework.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WooCommerce PHP API library here:
https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce

And use their documentation to retrieve your customer's data through an API call.
http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#retrieve-a-customer

Unfortunately, the password field is WRITE-ONLY, so you cannot retrieve the user password from your laravel application.

You could try a login where the user enters their email and phone number as verification, and pull that data from WooCommerce. If they match, log them into your Laravel app. But this is not the most secure method.

It's not really possible unless you were to use a WooCommerce Webhook to create a user in your database when a customer signs up for your WooCommerce. But even then, I believe that the password is not accessible for security reasons (unless you use some hacky, insecure plugins).

What I would recommend is using an SMS login for your Laravel app. Have the customer enter their WooCommerce phone number or email, use the WooCommerce API to see if a customer exists with that phone number, if it does, then generate a 6-digit temporary login password token and send it to the phone number via SMS or email. The customer can then login to your laravel app using their WooCommerce email and their temporary login token that they received through SMS or email. I think this would be the most secure way to do it.